# How can you create a list of lists while swapping numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list of numbers

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
```

I want to be able to generate many lists from this list while swapping the numbers.

```
L1 = [1,2,3] 
L2 = [2,1,3]
L3 = [3,2,1]
L4 = [1,3,2]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import permutations

print(list(permutations(L1)))
```

While give you a list of what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import permutations
L1 = [1,2,3]
for p in permutations(L1):
    print list(p)

output:

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```